# Python 2.7: get the size of a file just from its handle (and not its path)

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, filesize

I am writing a function that needs to do things on a file, based on the file-size (in bytes). I would like to minimize the number of parameters to pass to the function, so I would only pass the handle to the already-open file, and let the function get the size.
Is there an elegant way to do this?

I was trying the following, with `os.path.getsize(os.path.abspath(file_id))`, but it doesn't work:

```
def datafile_profiler(file_id):
    filesize = os.path.getsize(os.path.abspath(file_id))

    #[...] continue doing things with the file, based on the size in bites

    return stuff
```

and then, from the "main code"

```
file_id = open(filepath, "rb")
stuff = datafile_profiler(file_id)
file_id.close()
```

Any suggestion (also a totally different approach) is welcome.
Thaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something very similar like this:

```
filesize = os.path.getsize(file_id.name)
```

This will only work on `file` objects created using `open()` or similar functions, and that stores a local file name. If you change directories at some point, or another process replaces the file with something else, the file name will no longer point to the same file as the `file` object.

Another way to get the size of the file object that avoids the above problems is:

```
os.fstat(file_id.fileno()).st_size
```

Comment: I have to say, the second approach is indeed more robust, but the first one is much more readable (by humans) :)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the most straightforward way to do what you want without using name is by using seek and tell. Let's put it in an example.

```
def get_file_size(fd):
 fd.seek(0,2)
 return fd.tell()
```

There fd is the file descriptor. it could be an id got by using open or even a StringIO. it will work either way.

Comment: A good solution, though you'd need to save and restore the current position to factor it out into a function like this, where you can't assume the current file position can be casually discarded. I believe (not sure) it may not work properly when open in text mode though.

Comment: @ShadowRanger,it could be needed, but in this case just by calling tell before the seek and saving the position would be enough.

Comment: assuming the file is opened in a binary mode. For real files (with valid `.fileno()`), `os.fstat()` should be used if available.

Answer (score 0):

`file` objects have a `name` property, so you could write:

```
filesize = os.path.getsize(file_id.name)
```

Comment: If you already have an open file handle, Michael Hoffman's `fstat()` solution is much better, for the reasons stated in that answer.

Comment: Great point. @Fabio, thanks for accepting my answer but could you change that to accept Michael's instead? I think it's better than mine.